# Chef: How to rollback a run of cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I ran a cookbook which has installed some things (for example apache) on my chef node. It was the first version (0.1.0) of my cookbook. How can I undo the changes? (remove apache using chef)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific way, you would need to write a new recipe that enforces the new state you want (packages uninstalled, folders removed, services stopped, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Chef is not good with removing things unless you specified them explicitly. So there is no easy way.  You would require to write a recipe for resources you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @coderange. There is no defined way, but I would follow these steps:

1- Start by deleting the cookbook from the chef server, use `knife cookbook delete <cookbook_name>`

2- Create a new cookbook with a new recipe to undo the changes(apache, etc) from your initial cookbook.

3- Upload the new cookbook to the chef server `knife cookbook upload <new_cookbook_name>`

4- Check that after chef-client runs the node is back to the initial(or desired state).

Notes: In your case, I prefer adding a new cookbook with a new recipe instead of just adding a new recipe to your existing cookbook. It keeps thing clean and easy to understand. 
Also, when is time to clean up, you can delete the entire cookbook used to clean and nothing will be affected.